# Pure-ftpd on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, login, ftp

I've installed pure-ftpd on Ubuntu

but when i do :
ftp localhost

I can't login with Ubuntu (or any) user...

Answer (score 1):

Is perhaps your firewall active and blocking the FTP protocol?

- See the [Firewall section in the Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html).
- Have you checked the [Pure-FTPd FAQ](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ)?